# Tokenize newline and string literals across new line in F#

Tags: regex, parsing, f#

I'm working on a [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) parser with **F#**. In my current solution I split lines using:

```
let regex s = new Regex(s, RegexOptions.Compiled)
let linesRe = regex @"\r\n|\r|\n"
```

and lex tokens with:

```
let tokenRe = regex @"((?(\d+|\w+|(""\w+"")|\[|\]|.|=))\s*)*"
let tokenizeLine (s: string) =
  [for x in tokenRe.Match(s).Groups.["token"].Captures do
    let token =
      match x.Value with
      | "[" -> OPENBR
      // omissis...
      | s when isStringLiteral s -> STR (s.Substring(1, s.Length-2))
      | s -> ID s
    yield token]
```

In this way I'll be unable to handle multiline string defined as:

```
lines = '''
The first newline is
trimmed in raw strings.
   All other whitespace
   is preserved.
'''
```

As now I add a `NEWLINE` token on every line, but I would like to:

1. Capture each new line I match.
2. Capture multiline string as string literals.

I've found similar question but I was unable to even to just capture new line. I've tried adding the first pattern to the second (without splitting lines before) using various setting of `RegexOptions` (both `Singleline` and `Multiline`), but I've ended without matching new lines.

Comment: If you're writing a parser, perhaps [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec) would be a better fit than regular expressions...

Comment: Before I've considered [FsLex\FsYacc](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/) but I don't like much code generation tools (I've the feel of getting out of control)... I'll reconsider using a parser combinator library, looking at your **FParsec** suggestion.

Comment: While I am a big fan of FParsec FsLex/FsYacc has the benefit that the runtime of it can be encapsulated in a single assembly. With FParsec you need the FParsec F# assembly + the FParsec C# assembly (around ~1 Meg). In addition visible dependency are always problematic for reusable components.

Comment: @FuleSnabel, another little problem (that I think came from low maintenance) is that **NuGet** package doesn't get added to project. I had to compile it and set assemblies reference manually. In the last, this is few thing compared for what you get!

Comment: FYI; I wrote an EBNF grammar for TOXML (not fully completed), that might help you if you go for FParsec: https://github.com/mrange/toml/tree/mrange/ebnf#user-content-toml-ebnf-grammar

Comment: @FuleSnabel, yes it helps really! +1 It avoids me to scan informations on the TOML spec and a grammar is really the needed representation to map rules into code.

Comment: @FuleSnabel, sorry if this may be a little off topic here... But can you tell me if **TOML** accepts `null` literal like **JSON**? It seems it not (a good decision if true).

Comment: No I don't think null values exist in TOML, in any case someone has been working on a ABNF grammar that is probably more complete than my attempt: https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/pull/236/files

Comment: OK, thanks again for sharing it. I'll look to ABNF grammar too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split lines appears to be a first-pass or pre-process of your TOML file, this may be easier to do with a parser library like [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec) as suggested by Mark Seemann.

Another option would be to use a simple state machine to split the lines, e.g

```
let split separator (s:string) =
    let values = ResizeArray<_>()
    let rec gather start i qs =
        let add () = s.Substring(start,i-start) |> values.Add
        if i = s.Length then add()
        elif s.[i] = '"' && qs = 2 then inTripleQuotes start (i+1) 0
        elif s.[i] = '"' then gather start (i+1) (qs+1)
        elif s.[i] = separator then add(); gather (i+1) (i+1) 0
        else gather start (i+1) 0
    and inTripleQuotes start i qs =
        if s.[i] = '"' && qs = 2 then gather start (i+1) 0
        elif s.[i] = '"' then inTripleQuotes start (i+1) (qs+1)
        else inTripleQuotes start (i+1) 0
    gather 0 0 0
    values.ToArray()

split '\n' text
```

Inside the `split` function above I used 2 mutually recursive functions, `gather` to scan until a separator is reached and `inTripleQuotes` to skip separators within a triple quote block.

Comment: I've tested the function with this data `let text = sprintf "this \nis \"\"\"text on\nmore\nlines\"\"\" with 3\n quotes";;` on `fsharpi` and it perfectly fits in my actual solution. Anyway I'll go to deepen my knowledge of **FParsec**.

Comment: I want to add that **FParsec** is interesting because with parser combinators I can describe my syntax in a declarative way and internal design of the library seems also favor performance. Anyway the benefit of using this function and proceeding with a recursive descent parser (I'm writing) I can avoid adding a dependency to my code.

Comment: With FParsec you also get human-readable error messages for "free".

Comment: @gsscoder having looked at the spec for TOML more closely I think a hand rolled recursive descent parser is a valid option for this scenario., As you say it removes the need to take an external dependency. Just in case you may find the following JSON parser snippet using active patterns & regex helpfull: http://fssnip.net/8y

Comment: @Philip Trelford, again +1, link very appreciated! In this case I think that both path are viable. Recursive descent parser was my first choice (and I drafted some code w/ **F# interactive**), but I'm also evaluating **FParsec**. Yes, it's an external dependency but I really like how the code get shaped. Anyway, I'll study your snippet too.

Comment: @FuleSnabel, you're right and this is not little thing. I love also that it has an eye for performance: if you look at source code you'll (but maybe you already know) that a part is written in **C#** (I guess for that reason). Another point for **FParsec** is that code acts a sort of specification/grammar.